# Docker image of Java project

Tags: java, maven, docker, docker-build

I am trying make a docker image of a java project. I first created a directory and in that I created a docker.txt file. The files contains this

```
FROM java:8 

# Install maven
RUN apt-get update  
RUN apt-get install -y maven

WORKDIR /home/mmt/CouchBaseClient/CB-RestAPI/CouchBaseThinClient

# Prepare by downloading dependencies
ADD pom.xml /home/mmt/CouchBaseClient/CB-RestAPI/CouchBaseThinClient/pom.xml  
RUN ["mvn", "dependency:resolve"]  
RUN ["mvn", "verify"]

# Adding source, compile and package into a fat jar
ADD src /home/mmt/CouchBaseClient/CB-RestAPI/CouchBaseThinClient/src  
RUN ["mvn", "package"]

EXPOSE 4567  
CMD ["/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/java", "-jar", "target/sparkexample-jar-with-dependencies.jar"]
```

and then I run in terminal the following command

```
docker build -t API .
```

I get the following error

```
invalid value "API" for flag -t: Error parsing reference: "API" is not a valid repository/tag
See 'docker build --help'.
```

Comment: Did you paste the command correctly? It should be `docker build -t sometag .` (note the `.` at the end).

Comment: Oh! my bad . edited the post!

Comment: OK. And for sure your Docker file is called `Dockerfile` and not `docker.txt`, right?

Comment: No it is called docker.txt. Cant we use a different file name except Dockerfile?

Comment: If you don't set the `-f` option, not, see https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/

Comment: Oh Okay and I just found out that my daemon is not running. How do I run daemon?

Comment: I would start by making it work with the default file name that is Dockerfile (watch the casing). I would also ensure to discard API to be a reserved world, so called it just: "mycustomimage", it that works, then start trying to customize it.

Comment: Would'nt it be much easier to use an according [maven-plugin](http://ro14nd.de/docker-maven-plugin/docker-build.html) ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Docker is complaining about "API" in the sense that it's not allowed to have a tag name with one or more character in uppercase:

```
$ docker build -t FOO .
repository name component must match "[a-z0-9](?:-*[a-z0-9])*(?:[._][a-z0-9](?:-*[a-z0-9])*)*"
```

Usually "recipes" to build Docker images are written in a file named Dockerfile, anyway you can continue to use docker.txt using the `-f` option:

```
docker build -f docker.txt -t api .
```